# Understanding Buffering in C

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I am having a really hard time understanding the depths of buffering especially in C programming and I have searched for really long on this topic but haven't found something satisfying till now.

I will be a little more specific:
I do understand the concept behind it (i.e. coordination of operations by different hardware devices and minimizing the difference in speed of these devices) but I would appreciate a more full explanation of these and other potential reasons for buffering (and by full I mean full the longer and deeper the better) it would also be really nice to give some concrete Examples of how buffering is implemented in I/O streams.

The other questions would be that I noticed that some rules in buffer flushing aren't followed by my programs as weirdly as this sounds like the following simple fragment:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen("hallo.txt", "w");

    fputc('A', fp);
    getchar();
    fputc('A', fp);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The program is intended to demonstrate that impending input will flush arbitrary stream immediately when the first getchar() is called but this simply doesn't happen as often as I try it and with as many modifications as I want — it simply doesn't happen as for `stdout` (with `printf()` for example) the stream is flushed without any input requested also negating the rule therefore am I understanding this rule wrongly or is there something other to consider

I am using Gnu GCC on Windows 8.1.

Update:

I forgot to ask that I read on some sites how people refer to e.g. string literals as buffers or even arrays as buffers; is this correct or am I missing something?
Please explain this point too.

Comment: For your last question (from the update); yes, arrays (especially of characters) are referred to as buffers, but this is different from I/O buffering, even though I/O buffering typically uses a buffer to hold the data until it is written or read.

Comment: Why would `getchar()` from `stdin` flush your output file (which incidentally, you have not closed)?

Comment: If standard output is being written to a file, or pipe, or other non-interactive device, then the standard I/O library won't flush it before reading new data via `getchar()`.  Only if standard output goes to an interactive device will an implementation (normally) flush the standard output before reading on standard input.  Even then, if the data is already in the input buffer, it probably won't flush standard output.  I believe it is implementation defined behaviour, though.

Comment: I should add that the C standard says nothing about any synchronization between standard input and standard output.  That means any flushing behaviour I referred to is not standardized in C.  I didn't find any mention of it in POSIX either.

Comment: doesn't GNU mention any thing too?

Comment: @jonathanleffler I can comprehend why arrays and especially character arrays are called sometimes buffers but why are something like string literals also called buffers as they are not designed to be temporary memory where data are hold only for a short time because they are of type static storage class

Comment: @Lockon2000: string literals are not *usually* called buffers.  Where did you see this usage?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word *buffer* is used for many different things in computer science. In the more general sense, it is any piece of memory where data is stored temporarily until it is processed or copied to the final destination (or other buffer).

As you hinted in the question there are many types of buffers, but as a broad grouping:

1. Hardware buffers: These are buffers where data is stored before being moved to a HW device. Or buffers where data is stored while being received from the HW device until it is processed by the application. This is needed because the I/O operation usually has memory and timing requirements, and these are fulfilled by the buffer. Think of DMA devices that read/write directly to memory, if the memory is not set up properly the system may crash. Or sound devices that must have sub-microsecond precision or it will work poorly.
2. Cache buffers: These are buffers where data is grouped before writing into/read from a file/device so that the performance is generally improved.
3. Helper buffers: You move data into/from such a buffer, because it is easier for your algorithm.

Case #2 is that of your `FILE*` example. Imagine that a call to the *write* system call (`WriteFile()` in Win32) takes 1ms for just the call plus 1us for each byte (bear with me, things are more complicated in real world). Then, if you do:

```
FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "w");
for (int i=0; i < 1000000; ++i)
    fputc('x', f);
fclose(f);
```

Without buffering, this code would take `1000000 * (1ms + 1us)`, that's about 1000 seconds. However, with a buffer of 10000 bytes, there will be only 100 system calls, 10000 bytes each. That would be `100 * (1ms + 10000us)`. That's just 0.1 seconds!

Note also that the OS will do its own buffering, so that the data is written to the actual device using the most efficient size. That will be a HW and cache buffer at the same time!

About your problem with flushing, files are usually flushed just when closed or manually flushed. Some files, such as `stdout` are line-flushed, that is, they are flushed whenever a `'\n'` is written. Also the `stdin/stdout` are special: when you read from `stdin` then `stdout` is flushed. Other files are untouched, only `stdout`. That is handy if you are writing an interactive program.

My case #3 is for example when you do:

```
FILE *f = open("x.txt", "r");
char buffer[1000];
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f);
int n;
sscanf(buffer, "%d", &n);
```

You use the buffer to hold a line from the file, and then you parse the data from the line. Yes, you could call `fscanf()` directly, but in other APIs there may not be the equivalent function, and moreover you have more control this way: you can analyze the type if line, skip comments, count lines...

Or imagine that you receive one byte at a time, for example from a keyboard. You will just accumulate characters in a buffer and parse the line when the Enter key is pressed. That is what most interactive console programs do.

Comment: I want to verify some points first is the slower device always the target device I mean for example in writing to a file it is obvious that the hard disk is slower than the processor and ram but in receiving input form a file on the hard disk which one is slower is it the hard to write on the buffer or the processor to process the data received to be even more clear is the data accumulated very fast and then processed at pace or the other way - I hope my question is clear enough

Comment: @Lockon2000: That depends on what you do with the data. If you want to write, for example, freshly mined bitcoins into a file, then the CPU will be slower than the HD. In that case you will not buffer several BTs before writing, you'll write&flush immediately. You still have buffers where the BTs are computed before being saved, of course. Same for readers: if your CPU discards the data, the HD is slower, but if you do heave computations, then the CPU is slower. It will work because any sane implementation will limit the maximum size of pending buffers and block the fastest process.

Comment: from your last edit - first: if the stdout is only flushed when the newline character is encountered or only with input from stdin ( please see my comment a little below ) then why is on my system the stdout flushed with out even requesting any input or displaying any newline as I mentioned
second: I seem to misunderstand something from your last lines if the input from the keyboard is accumulated key after key and then sent to the processer also one after one because the program cant handle chunks only individual bytes then where are the chunks I mean what is the reason behind the buffering

Comment: @Lockon2000: About 1st: sorry but I just don't understand what you are asking (no offense, but I find your lack of punctuation very difficult to read). 2nd: In the keyboard case, the buffer is needed because `sscanf()` takes a buffer. There are no functions that parse complex syntaxes taking one byte at a time. Well, you may write one, just do de buffering internally!

Comment: yes you are right I didn't notice it until now and will not ignore it from now on.
to the question again: okay lets try to put it differently; if the cases where stdout is flushed are only impending input form stdin ( specifically ), or encountering a newline; then why does my system flush the stdout ( for example after a printf("hay") ) without there being any newline, or requesting input from stdout?
and Please see the first mentiond rules in this site http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flushing-Buffers.html#Flushing-Buffers

Comment: @Lockon2000: The first GNU rule just says that the buffer size is limited, and when it is full, the contents are flushed to the destination. I considered that obvious and didn't mention it (my fault, added to the answer). Anyway, the details of buffering are implementation dependent, so your system may do funny things. It is impossible to say without knowing more details.

Answer (score 3):

The noun "buffer" really refers to a usage, not a distinct thing.  Any block of storage can serve as a buffer.  The term is intentionally used in this general sense in conjunction with various I/O functions, though the docs for the C I/O stream functions tend to avoid that.  Taking the POSIX `read()` function as an example, however: "**read()** attempts to read up to *count* bytes from file descriptor *fd* into the buffer starting at *buf*".  The "buffer" in that case simply means the block of memory in which the bytes read will be recorded; it is ordinarily implemented as a `char[]` or a dynamically-allocated block.

One uses a buffer especially in conjunction with I/O because some devices (especially hard disks) are most efficiently read in medium-to-large sized chunks, where as programs often want to consume that data in smaller pieces.  Some other forms of I/O, such as network I/O, may inherently come in chunks, so that you must record each whole chunk (in a buffer) or else lose that part you're not immediately ready to consume.  Similar considerations apply to output.

As for your test program's behavior, the "rule" you hoped to demonstrate is specific to console I/O, but only one of the streams involved is connected to the console.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is a bit too broad. Buffering is used in many cases, including message storage before actual usage, DMA uses, speedup usages and so on. In short, the entire buffering thing can be summarized as "save my data, let me continue execution while you do something with the data".

Sometimes you may modify buffers after passing them to functions, sometimes not. Sometimes buffers are hardware, sometimes software. Sometimes they reside in RAM, sometimes in other memory types.

So, please ask more specific question. As a point to begin, use wikipedia, it is almost always helpful: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer)

As for the code sample, I haven't found any mention of all output buffers being flushed upon `getchar`. Buffers for files are generally flushed in three cases:

1. `fflush()` or equivalent
2. File is closed
3. The buffer is overflown.

Since neither of these cases is true for you, the file is not flushed (note that application termination is **not** in this list).

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Flushing-Buffers.html#Flushing-Buffers
the last rule specifies it very clearly that any input on any stream should flush the streams at least if I am understanding it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Buffer is a simple small area inside your memory (RAM) and that area is responsible of storing information before sent to your program, as long I'm typing the characters from the keyboard these characters will be stored inside the buffer and as soon I press the Enter key these characters will be transported from the buffer into  your program so with the help of buffer all these characters are instantly available to your program (prevent lag and the slowly) and sent them to the output display screen